# Find out where in user code an internal .Net exception originated

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms

I am currently working on an existing Windows Forms application (VB.net), and am busy reworking the exception handling mechanism.

Currently, a lot of methods in the code are just surrounded with try/catch block that catches a generic exception and then calls a utility method that just shows the user a messagebox informing him of the error, and then logging it.

So in a lot of cases no corrective action is taken and the exception is just logged. I know this probably isn't the best way but that's they way we're gonna have to do it for the near future.

Anyway, I wanted to do this in a more generic way, so I hooked up Application.ThreadException and AppDomain.UnhandledException.

This seems to work well, except for one inconvenience. Whenever an error gets thrown from the .net runtime itself, or a 3rd party control, the stacktrace begins there where the exception is thrown in the framework-methods or 3rd party methods (obviously!).

But it would be handier if I had an easy way of finding out exactly where these exceptions cross the boundary into my code. I would like an easy way of determining (in Application.ThreadException) where in my own code an exception originated.

I am aware this information is contained in the Exception.StackTrace property, but I would like an easy way to get to this specific information seeing as the stacktrace property is one huge string.

Basically I would like the class, method and line number where the exception first bubbled up into my code.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use this kind of code:

```
[STAThread] static void Main() {
  try {
    Application.Run(new Form1());
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    //do smth with exception
  }
}
```

It will catch exceptions raised only by your code, when in the same time `AppDomain.UnhandledException` can be more verbose. This, certainly,  will work only for main thread.

Comment: So if my code calls a 3rd party control and that control throws an exception, will it be caught by the code you suggested? And what will be the origin point of the Stacktrace?

Comment: I believe origin point will be in the 3rd party control, but it will also contain your code too.

Comment: I just tried this in a little test project and it doesn't seem to work. When running in debug (visual studio) I can catch the exception like you suggested, but after that my application automatically shuts down. And if I try this in release mode I just get a standard .Net messagebox for an unhandled exception, just like I would get if I didn't catch the error at all

Comment: Try Dim testForm As TestForm = New TestForm() Application.Run(testForm) Catch ex As Exception MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace) End Try. And the form just contains a button that does: Throw New NullReferenceException()

Comment: @Quagmire let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1802/discussion-between-restuta-and-quagmire)